# Why is this not working? (fetch()/ getJSON() from WIX)

Tags: javascript, api, velo

I have written the following code to access the companies house api (https://developer.company-information.service.gov.uk/). I have googled and tried many things and I have no idea how to get data from this api using fetch/ getJSON. Please help. I am new to javascript.

```
import { getJSON } from 'wix-fetch';
const baseURL = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk"

export function call_companieshouse_api(endpt, search_param){

    var api_key = btoa(key)
    var url = baseURL + endpt + search_param
  
    getJSON(url, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + api_key,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"},
        credentials: "include",
        mode: "cors"
        })
        .then(json => console.log(json.someKey))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `console.log(url)` to confirm that it's in the proper format?

Comment: So what is the error? What is logged? What are the values for `endpt` and `search_param`Impossible`? It is hard for us to guess.

Comment: I high doubt wix tag is meant for wix-fetch

Comment: The error is the following: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: The error is the following: TypeError: Failed to fetch. endpt="/search/companies?q=" and search_param is a company number. I've written python and VBA code that makes use of the API often, so I am sure that these values are correct and working. The bit that confuses me is how to connect to the API from within wix.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work!
I'm not exactly sure how, but I will explain what I have done (apart from the obvious code change).
I created a new backend file .jsw and in this file is the following code.

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';
import btoa from 'btoa'
const baseURL = 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk';
var api_key = 'the api key';

export function call_companieshouse_api(endpt, search_param){
    var url = baseURL + endpt + search_param;
    var base64_key = btoa(api_key)

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64_key,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'},
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: "cors"
        }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

I then have a button click event function with the following code.

```
export function button1_click(event) {

    var search_param = $w('#input1').value;

    if (search_param.length <= 1) {
        $w('#box1').show();
        return;
    }

    var endpt = "/search/companies?q="

    call_companieshouse_api(endpt, search_param)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```